# Why does it say FBX module not found even though it is installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, fbx

Note* I got this code from the internet

I am trying to run a python script to validate the texture dimensions in an fbx file. I have declared a list of dimensions that can be used and if the dimensions of the texture used does not comply with the specified dimensions then the code will return an error.

But when I try to run the code, python is not able to find the FBX module. It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anirudh.b.SMARTAPT\Downloads\htm-fbx-introduction_to_the_python_fbx_sdk (2)\fbxTextureChecker-p1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import fbx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbx'
```

I looked up the issue in the internet and found nothing of use. I use Python 3.7 and have all the required modules installed through pip. I installed the FBX SDK and the Python binding through installer and copied the necessary files to the Python37\Lib\site-packages (tried both 64x and 86x bit files).

Could it be that the issue is due to my python version. Do I need to use some other version? Is there any way to make the script work in Python3.7 itself?

```
import fbx
import Image
import sys

filepath = r'C:\Autodesk\cubeMan.fbx'
validTextureDimensions = [ (256, 256), (512, 512) ]
manager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()
importer = fbx.FbxImporter.Create( manager, 'myImporter' )
status = importer.Initialize( filepath )

if status == False:
    print('FbxImporter initialization failed.')
    print('Error: %s' % importer.GetLastErrorString())
    sys.exit()

scene = fbx.FbxScene.Create( manager, 'myScene' )
importer.Import( scene )
importer.Destroy()
textureArray = fbx.FbxTextureArray()
scene.FillTextureArray( textureArray )
invalidTextures = {}

for i in range( 0, textureArray.GetCount() ):        
    texture = textureArray.GetAt( i )
    if texture.ClassId == fbx.FbxFileTexture.ClassId:
        textureFilename = texture.GetFileName()
        image = Image.open( textureFilename )
        width, height = image.size
        if (width, height) not in validTextureDimensions:
            invalidTextures[ textureFilename ] = (width, height)
            print('Invalid dimensions (%sx%s) - %s\n' % (width, height, textureFilename ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use python 2.7 instead of 3.7.
It is working for me with 2.7.

https://help.autodesk.com/view/FBX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_2F3A42FA_4C19_42F2_BC4F_B9EC64EA16AA_htm